# Clarification of dnf list output

Tags: dnf

I just installed Centos stream 9.  I'm trying to understand the output of `dnf list`.  There appear to be three columns.  The far right column is filled with mostly "anaconda", "AppStream", "baseos".

Or the same, but with an `@` at the front, eg: `@anaconda`. What's the difference, and what are these things?  All I was trying to do is look through the official repo for available programs.

Comment: Please show us the actual output you are trying to understand instead of describing it. That will help us understand what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last column shows the origin of the package:

- Anaconda is the name of the installer, and `@anaconda` means that the package was installed by the installer;
- BaseOS is the core of the operating system;
- AppStream is a repository providing non-core applications, runtime languages, databases etc.;
- Extras contains repository packages giving access to even more repositories.

See [this CentOS 8 FAQ entry](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/managing-userspace-components/assembly_using-appstream/#distribution-of-content-in-rhel8_using-appstream) for details.

An `@` prefix indicates that the listed package is installed.